# Как получить прямую ссылку на YouTube видео в формате mp3?

Tags: python, youtube

мне надо с помощью python получать прямую ссылку на YouTube видео в формате mp3. Дело в том, что например pytube предоставляет мне только 5 ссылок на аудио, и они все в формате .webm. Мне же надо mp3, при этом не скачивая видео (так бы просто скачал без проблем и конвертировал). Возможно ли это осуществить? Может с помощью другой библиотеки?

Comment: Невозможно, потому что youtube не хранит mp3 у себя, только aac (mp4a) или opus (webm)

Comment: Через сторонний сайт, например, https://ytmp3.mobi/developers/